# When minikube on Mac is asked for URL, why does it instead start a service in a tunnel?

Tags: zsh, minikube, macos-catalina

I installed the latest Docker, Minikube, and kubectl into my Mac (Catalina).  I also have a recent MySQL, with the command line properly installed in the PATH.  I'm using the stock terminal (zsh).

Docker started just fine, tells me of the pods it has installed.

Minikube starts fine, and kubectl get all reports on its artifacts just fine.

```
Jeromes-MacBook-Pro:cloudnative-statelessness jerome$ kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mysql-7dbfd4dbc4-sz8ps   1/1     Running   0          15m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          20m
service/mysql-svc    NodePort    10.111.176.15   <none>        3306:30022/TCP   15m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mysql   1/1     1            1           15m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mysql-7dbfd4dbc4   1         1         1       15m
```

When I run minikube service mysql-svc --url I'm expecting to get a URL, like this one from another machine:  http://192.168.99.101:31067  .  Instead I see something about starting a service in a 'tunnel':

```
Jeromes-MacBook-Pro:cloudnative-statelessness jerome$ minikube service mysql-svc --url
  Starting tunnel for service mysql-svc.
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |   NAME    | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | mysql-svc |             | http://127.0.0.1:64966 |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
http://127.0.0.1:64966
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

At this point the terminal is non-responsive.

I'm believing that minikube service SERVICENAME should try to start a service, and also return that block of text.  I'm also believing that the --url suffix should merely returns what is in the URL column, and skip starting a service.

Any good explanations of how I can get the result I want on my Mac?

And BTW, how do I recover control of the terminal session once it states "Because..."  ?

Thanks,

Jerome.

**UPDATE ON 8/14/2020:**

I took Saravanan's advice.  I uninstalled Docker from my Mac and used homebrew to install docker + docker-machine + virtualbox (see https://www.robinwieruch.de/docker-macos).  When I run "minikube service mysql-svc --url" I no longer get the tunnel problem.  Thank you, Saravanan.

My problems have morphed into getting a correct version of my containers (compiled apps, then run thru docker build) from Docker Hub.  The YAML file I have points at my account there, but I'm afraid I've an obsolete version.  What do I do to overwrite my current version on my Mac, or to delete the Docker containers so that kubectl create can get the updated version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is your minikube image is running in the container.
Try changing the configuration to run it in the virtual box. Then you can reach your sql pod without tunneling.

```
# first delete the existing minikube image
$ minikube delete

# change the minikube driver to virtualbox
$ minikube config set vm-driver virtualbox

# start minikube again
$ minikube start
```

> Ensure you have virtual box installed before proceeding

Comment: I installed "Docker for Mac" rather than the docker + virtualbox explicitly.  The Docker for Max has HyperV, etc.  Does that change your instructions?  Or, perhaps, what should my Docker installation be on Mac Catalina?

Comment: This might be because of the networking differences between minikube running in docker and virtual box. I don't know about that networking. I have came across a similar issue and changing the minikube driver has saved me and I thought of sharing this with you.

Comment: I have removed Docker and installed docker + docker-machine + virtualbox according to advice on https://www.robinwieruch.de/docker-macos .  I no longer get the tunnel.  I've updated the original complaint, with a hat tip to you, about how to ensure I've the latest image of my app fetched from Docker Hub.